# Facebook android: passing facebook object between activities

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want to make an application that user will login in one activity with a button which call facebook login thing from facebook_android_sdk and I want to send a wall post in second activity which comes after user logins. I want to pass facebook object between activities. I tried serializable and parcelable, but didn't work ! Can someone guide me for this ?
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your token and expires via SharedPerferences, then create new Facebook object in second activity, set token and expires from SharedPreferences and check validity. Thats all! [Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and here sample:

```
//facebook token and expires
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
if(access_token != null) {
   facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
}
if(expires != 0) {
   facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
}
if (facebook.isSessionValid()) {
// Do your work here
}
```

Comment: i saved with this code 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

Comment: and got on new activity with this code. 
  SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",
             MODE_PRIVATE);
  String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
  long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
  facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
  facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);

but I am getting runtime exception. do you know anything about it?

Comment: and do you save and read same preferences? because you read "facebook" preferences and i don't know what preferences you save

Comment: I saved with this '                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit()'

Comment: and read with this code `  facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
  SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",
             MODE_PRIVATE);
  String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
  Log.d("asd", access_token);
  long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
  facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
  facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);`

is it wrong?

Comment: try save like this: SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",           MODE_PRIVATE);SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); instead of this:SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();

Comment: still getting Runtime exception. It happens when i want to print access_token in second activity to log

Comment: what kind of exception? i guess, it is NullPointerException?

Comment: yeah. i think, i can not read shared memory
E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: carefully check how you save and read token and expires, because problem is probabaly in this

Comment: can you give your e-mail ? i send you screenshots if it is ok?

Comment: for saving 
                         SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook", MODE_PRIVATE);
                         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();

Comment: for reading
  facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
  SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook",
             MODE_PRIVATE);
  String access_token = prefs.getString("access_token", null);
  Log.d("asd", access_token);
  long expires = prefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
  facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
  facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);

That is it. I am saving in login block oncomplete method, and reading in second activity oncreate method.

Comment: post your code for saving. and are you sure that your autoriztion successful?

Comment: for saving SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("facebook", MODE_PRIVATE); SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken()); editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires()); editor.commit();

Comment: are you sure that your facebook authoriztion successfull? if no, OnComplete methon won't be executed and nothing will be saved. Your reading and saving seems legit

Comment: I am getting access_token at second activity right now but can't send wall post. it gives got response: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}} error :(

Comment: delete your app and try again

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the [easyfacebookandroidsdk](http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/)

I have used this api in my [project](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.post.ticker&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wb3N0LnRpY2tlciJd) it's better and easy to use.

Comment: I did nearly everything on my project, i can do the features vie facebook_android_sdk. I didn't take a real look easyfacebookandroidsdk but have not so much time to learn it too. is it too different from facebook android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared preference for passing session between the activities.

```
bundle.putSerializable();
```

Session class implements Serializable